# 4clojure inconsistent with local Clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure, fibonacci

I've been going through problems in [4Clojure](http://www.4clojure.com/). There's [Problem 26](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/26) which requires you to generate first *n* Fibonacci numbers. I wanted to solve it using lazy sequences and anonymous functions and this is my solution:

```
#(let [fib-seq (lazy-seq (map +
  (cons 0 (cons 0 fib-seq))
  (cons 1 fib-seq)))]
   (take % fib-seq))
```

It works fine when I test it on various arguments in CIDER (Emacs), but 4clojure rejects this solution giving the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: fib-seq in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:0)
```

Do you have any idea why they might behave inconsistently? My local version of Clojure is 1.5.1

EDIT: Here's what worked for me in the end:

```
#(letfn [(fib-seq []
    ((fn rfib [a b] 
        (cons a (lazy-seq (rfib b (+ a b)))))
            1 1))]
    (take % (fib-seq)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you have a `fib-seq` `var` in your REPL session. This will not work in a fresh REPL. A binding in `let` cannot refer to its left-hand side. That is, in Scheme parlance Clojure's `let` is not a `letrec`. You could do this with `letfn` instead.

Comment: I figured out the `letfn` solution in the meantime :). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the version of clojure.jar used in 4clojure is before 1.5, because the function reduced(supported in clojure.1.5) is not supported in 4clojure